# ASP.net MVC File Content-Length

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The code below is a greatly simplified test action in a new MVC project. The action is meant to return a simple text file containing the word `test`.

```
public ActionResult FileTest()
{
    return File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"), "text/plain", "test.txt");
}
```

When viewing the HTTP response from the server I would expect to see a header with `Content-Length: 4`, instead I see `Content-Length: 122`

Chrome and IE seem perfectly capable of coping with the miss match in `Content-Length` verses the number of bytes actually returned. Firefox (v47) however fails to download the file, indefinitely showing 4 of 122 bytes downloaded.

My question is: Is the behaviour I'm witnessing something I'm doing incorrectly, or is this a defect in the framework? Secondly, what I can do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I cross checked your code and it seems to be working fine on FireFox v47.

I suggest changing the return type from "ActionResult" to "FileResult" for returning files. This may resolve your issue. Let me know if you still face the same issue.

Comment: Thank-you for your suggestion however changing to FileResult has not made an difference.
Out of interest on your tests what is the Content-Length header being returned as?

Comment: Content length was 122 but Firefox still download the text file and i was able to open it.

Comment: I've just updated my installation of Firefox to v47.0.1 and the issue is resolved. I can't see anything related in the release notes which would explain the behaviour.
I'd still be interested in understanding why MVC is returning incorrect Content-Length headers.